# OOP - Accessing public "this" inside each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function to loop through some table rows but I need to use this.isempty instead of isempty. How do I access this inside of an each loop.

Code:

```
function checkValues(look) {
    this.isempty = 1;   
    this.search = $(look).find("input").each(function(){                        
        if ($.trim($(this).val())!="") {
            this.isempty = 0;
        }
    }); 
    return this.isempty;
}
```

Obviously the `this.isempty = 0;` will not work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a closure variable in this case to refer `isempty`

```
function checkValues(look) {
    this.isempty = 1;
    var self = this;
    this.search = $(look).find("input").each(function () {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) != "") {
            self.isempty = 0;
        }
    });
    return this.isempty;
}
```

---

But a more appropriate way here is to use .filter() like

```
function checkValues(look) {
    this.isempty = 1;
    this.search = $(look).find("input").;
    this.isempty = this.search.filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value) != '';
    }).length > 0;
    return this.isempty;
}
```

Comment: With the first method, I realise that using the each is not the best way to do it but is the var self = this; the correct way of doing that?

Comment: @FirstLegion AFAIK in this given scenario that is the best way

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to reference `this` because of a constraint in your code? Would the following work?

```
function checkValues(look) {   
    var isEmpty = 1;
    $(look).find("input").each(function(){                        
        if ($.trim($(this).val())!="") {
            isEmpty = 0;
            return false; // Breaks out of the loop for a little performance boost
        }
    }); 
    return isEmpty;
}
```

Comment: Return false in the each loop does not work as it just exits the each loop. It works as a "break" in this case. Also, doesn't tell me how to use the "this" inside of the each.

Comment: From the sample you gave, you don't need to access `this`. Are you using this method as a constructor that you need to store values on `this`?

Comment: I just gave that as an example as I wanted to know how to do this for other cases. Thank you though.